# My echo is destroying my div container / row

Tags: php, post, bootstrap-4, echo, blogs

So I want to show my posts with a variable and echo the html form out. 
The problem is, that I need

```
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
```

cause I want it to be displayed in a row. But cause every post got that div classes, it doesnt work and displays the posts completely wrong...

Moreover it shows my buttons "Loeschen" and "Bearbeiten" on top but it should be right below the text field.

How it should look:

[image: Example of how It should look]

How it actually looks now:

[image: And that's how it actually looks]

```
<?php   
        $ort = 'Beitr&auml;ge';
        include ("head.php");
        include("database.php");
        include("navigation.php");

?>
<!--Beitrage auflisten-->
<?php 

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM beitrag ORDER BY beitrag_id DESC";

    $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());

    $beitrag = "";

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
            $beitrag_id = $row['beitrag_id'];
            $titel = $row['titel'];
            $leistung = $row['leistung'];
            $bezugsort = $row['bezugsort'];
            $kosten = $row['kosten'];
            $p_text = $row['p_text'];



        $beitrag .= "  

        <div class='album py-5 bg-light'>
        <div class='container'>
        <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-md-4'>
          <div class='card mb-4 box-shadow'>
             <div class='card-header'>
                <a href='siehe_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'><h4 class='my-0 font-weight-normal'>$titel</h4></a
                <h4 class='my-0 font-weight-normal'>$kosten&euro;</h4 >
                </div>
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p class='card-text'>$p_text</p>
                    <div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>"; 


    if (isset($_SESSION["login"])){ 
                if($_SESSION["login"] == 1){
                    echo "  
                    <div class='btn-group' >
                            <a href='loeschen_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Loeschen</button>
                            <a href='bearbeiten_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Bearbeiten</button>
                            </div>";
                    }else{
                    echo "";
                }
            }





        }
        echo $beitrag;
    } else {
        echo "Keine BeitrĂ¤ge vorhanden ";
    }

    ?>  

    <a href='neuer_beitrag.php' target='_blank'>Neuer Beitrag</a>
```

The final version:
[Thanks to aynber and the others, now it works like I imagined it <3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekbha.png)

Comment: You're creating a new container/row for each record. Start/end them outside of the loop, then use a counter to close/start if it hits a certain number.

Comment: How can I start/end them outside of  the loop?

Comment: Actually, now that I'm messing with the code, you're missing a few ending div tags, but I'll create an answer that will show you how to use the loop better, as well as fix the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues: 1) You aren't closing all of the div tags, and 2) you're creating a new container with a width of 4 columns for each row. You'll want to create a new container outside of the loop, and only close/reopen if there are more than 3 results:

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0) {
    $i = 0; // Create a counter to see when to start a new row
    $beitrag .= "

            <div class='album py-5 bg-light'>
            <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        $beitrag_id = $row['beitrag_id'];
        $titel = $row['titel'];
        $leistung = $row['leistung'];
        $bezugsort = $row['bezugsort'];
        $kosten = $row['kosten'];
        $p_text = $row['p_text'];


        $beitrag .= "

            <div class='col-md-4'>
                <div class='card mb-4 box-shadow'>
                    <div class='card-header'>
                        <a href='siehe_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'><h4 class='my-0 font-weight-normal'>$titel</h4></a
                        <h4 class='my-0 font-weight-normal'>$kosten&euro;</h4 >
                    </div>
                    <div class='card-body'>
                        <p class='card-text'>$p_text</p>
                        <div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
                        </div>
                    </div>";

        if(isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == 1) {
                $beitrag .= "
                        <div class='btn-group' >
                                <a href='loeschen_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Loeschen</button>
                                <a href='bearbeiten_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Bearbeiten</button>
                                </div>";

        }

        $beitrag .= "    </div>
            </div>";

        $i++;

        if($i % 3 == 0) { // 3 results in the div, start a new one
            $beitrag .= "
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>";
            $beitrag .= "

            <div class='album py-5 bg-light'>
            <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>";
        }


    }

    if(($i - 1) % 3 != 0) { // It would have been closed on the last loop
        $beitrag .= "
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>";
    }

    echo $beitrag;
}
```

Comment: I am really grateful, thank you very much!! That solved my problem with the colums and rows of the posts. The only thing now is that I need to get the buttons in the right place below the posts.

Comment: You probably need to move the logic right after where you close the card-body div.

Comment: Do you mean my if(isset($_SESSION["login"])) logic? Cause when I move it where card-body div is closing, it doesnt change the position :/

Comment: Correct. Just make sure you put it in the proper place. You can view the source of the page in the browser or use the browser's developer tools to decide where the best place to put it would be.

Comment: Alright, I tried it in diffrerent location - without success. I am sorry, but could you please help me out with this one for the last time.

Comment: I've edited my answer. The issue actually was that you were echoing out the button instead of adding it to the string.

Comment: Oh you are right...God thank you, that really helped me a lot. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the html, you are not closing the link of the buttons.

```
<div class='btn-group' >
                            <a href='loeschen_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Loeschen</button></a>
                            <a href='bearbeiten_beitrag.php?pid=$beitrag_id'>
                                <button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary'>Bearbeiten</button></a>
                            </div>
```

Comment: oh thank you! but unfortunate it doesnt solve the placing problem.